# Java swagger-ui doesn't render allowableValues for parameter

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jax-rs, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a SpringBoot, JAX-RS, and Maven app.  I'm using Swagger annotations to provide info on the REST service interface.  It basically works, but I'm having trouble with some parameters that I expect a limited set of values.  I believe I'm specifying the "@Api..." annotations correctly, and I can see the expected results in the swagger.json file, but the swagger-ui doesn't appear to do anything with that information.

My pom.xml appears to specify version 1.5.20 of the swagger artifacts.

The following is a heavily elided excerpt from the Java interface:

```
@GET
@Path("...")
@ApiOperation("...")
@ApiImplicitParams({
    ...
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "poi_types", value = "Types of locations to include",
                      allowableValues = "pos, wifi, country",
                      dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
    ...
    })
public Object ...(@QueryParam(...)
                              @ApiParam(name = ..., value = "...")
                  String ...) {
```

In the swagger.json, I see the following for that entry:

```
    {
        "name" : "poi_types",
        "in" : "query",
        "description" : "Types of locations to include",
        "required" : false,
        "type" : "string",
        "enum" : [ "pos", "wifi", "country" ]
    }
```

In the generated UI, I see the following:

[image: swagger-ui excerpt for poi_types]

I've seen somewhere some mentions of possible disconnects between the required schema and what swagger-ui renders, like perhaps requiring a "schema" element in the parameter definition that includes the "type"and "enum" properties.  I tried manually changing the swagger.json to include that, but it made no difference.

Can anyone provide any background here?

**Update**:

I upgraded to swagger-core and swagger-annotations v1.6.2.  I also tried putting "allowableValues" into an "@ApiParam" instead of just an "@ApiImplicitParam".  Neither of these changes made any difference.  I don't see any indication in the UI of the allowable values.

This is the changed element from the @ApiParam change:

```
    {
      "name" : "isocc2",
      "in" : "query",
      "description" : "Country code",
      "required" : false,
      "type" : "string",
      "enum" : [ "en", "es" ]
    }
```

This is how this displays in the swagger UI:

[image: view of parameter with allowableValues]

I also verified from the browser the swagger.json that it loaded, and it matches what I expected.

Just in case, I tested it in Chrome in addition to Firefox.

What else could be wrong here?

Comment: suggest you use the latest swagger version.

Comment: I tried it on the latest openapi 2.x release, which is 1.6.2, and it made no difference.

Comment: I think we have some jars missing. Please chahe if annotations need need to change as well with new version??

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ?

```
public Object ...(@QueryParam(...)
                  @ApiParam(name = ..., value = "...", 
                            allowableValues = "pos, wifi, country",)
                  String poi_types) {
```

`allowableValues` property works well on `@ApiParam.`

Comment: So you're saying that it works for @ApiParam, but not for @ApiImplicitParam? The docs clearly state it is supported.

Comment: And I just tried this, and it doesn't work, at least not with version 1.6.2 of swagger-*.

Comment: I got this working with springfox-2.9.2 and 3.0.0 , which uses swagger version 1.5.20 :(